# Cannot read property merge of undefined , Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Table Component and I wanna integrate it with my back-end server but I keep getting an error called "Cannot read property merge of undefined "

I'm implementing the method connect in my DataSource, but I didn't get success reaching the data from the backend on this method in production. However, it works in development. Is it the correct method? If yes, how can I implement it? If no, what is the best method to fetch data from the server in my DataSource? This following last try resulted in an infinite loop adding data to my table

```
connect(): Observable<Student[]> {
    //events to listen
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this._sort.mdSortChange,
      this._paginator.page,
      this._filterChange,
    ];

    // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
    this._sort.mdSortChange.subscribe(() => {
      this._paginator.pageIndex = 0;
    });

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges)
      .startWith(null)
      .switchMap(() => {
        //call the service method which should return the data
        return this.studentService.query(this._paginator.pageIndex);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // Catch exceptions
        return Observable.of(null);
      })
      .map(result => {
        // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        return result;
      })
      .map(result => {
        if (!result) { return []; }

        //set results length (for pagination reasons)
        this.resultsLength = result.tableData.total;

        //return fetched data
        return result.students;
      });

  }
```

Comment: Maybe you might change the first map... To indicate that a loading has finished you can use pipe with finalize and this ensure that the request has finished.

Comment: What RxJS version are you using? You're attempting the syntax for RxJS v5+ whereas possibly you could be using RxJS v6+.

Comment: @MichaelD yeah I am using RxJs 6.5.5

Comment: @Takatalvi I tried that too but still getting the same error in production

Comment: Oh sure. It's just an advice to use the proper operator :P sorry. Your problem is with that Observable cause it's undefined so when it reads the Observable.merge would be something like undefined.merge

Comment: It appears somehow your production environment is RxJS v6+ and your development is RxJS v5+. Try to use RxJS v5+ instead of RxJS 6.5.5. The syntax here is for RxJS v5+.